# Добавление элементов в таблицу. Html & Js

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь понять как добавлять эллементы в таблицу. Вот код

```
localStorage.setItem('faucet1' '1');

var faucet1 = localStorage.getItem('faucet1');
if
 (faucet1 == '1') { 
var tr = document.createElement("tr");

tr.innerHTML('<td>гег </td> <td> </td> <td> 
гег</td> <td> гег </td> <td> гег</td> ');

}
 else {
alert('error');
}
</script>
 <html>
<table>
<tr> <th colspan="2">Кран</th> 
<th>Выплата</th> 
<th>Время</th> 
<th>Ссылка</th> </tr>

<!-- Нужно добавлять строчки в этот участок и 
дальше -->
```

Не могу разобраться, как указать куда добавлять элементы. Как добавлять элементы.

Я совсем новичок. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: начните с чтения: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылки по теме:
Поиск элемента - https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom
Добавление элемента на страницу - https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document
Если потребуется добавлять что-то в конкретную ячейку, то нужно изучить делегирование - https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

```js
//Дополнительный совет - не загрязняйте глобальное пространство переменными, лучше объявите функцию, которая будет добавлять вашу разметку в таблицу и объявляйте переменные в ней
function myFunc() {

  //Для начала, вам нужно найти элемент, в который нужно вставить вашу разметку. Вданном случае таблицу с id='table'.
  var table = document.getElementById('table');

//Тут выдерните ваше значение из locslStorage, я просто присвою 1.
  var faucet1 = 1;
  //Теперь создаем строку и присваиваем ее переменной.
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  
  if (faucet1 == 1) {

//добавляем разметку в созданную строку
    tr.innerHTML = '<td>гег </td> <td> </td> <td> гег</td> <td> гег </td> <td> гег</td>';

//вставляем строку в таблицу
    table.appendChild(tr);

  } else {
  
    console.log('error');
    
  }

};

myFunc();
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    <table id='table'>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Кран</th>
        <th>Выплата</th>
        <th>Время</th>
        <th>Ссылка</th>
      </tr>

      <!-- Нужно добавлять строчки в этот участок и 
    дальше -->
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```